# Sending email using SES in typescript

Tags: typescript, amazon-ses

I am trying to set up email service using ses in typescript. I followed this example https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/master/javascript/example_code/ses/ses_sendemail.js but I get

> AWS.ses is not a constructor.

Here is my emailService class

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const loggerService: LoggerServiceInterface = new LoggerService();

AWS.config.update({region: "us-east-1"});

export class EmailService {

sendEmail(recipient: string): Promise<boolean> {

 const params = {
  Destination: { /* required */
    CcAddresses: [
      "abcd@gmail.com",
      /* more items */
    ],
    ToAddresses: [
      "abcd@gmail.com",
      /* more items */
    ]
  },
  Message: { /* required */
    Body: { /* required */
      Html: {
       Charset: "UTF-8",
       Data: "HTML_FORMAT_BODY"
      },
      Text: {
       Charset: "UTF-8",
       Data: "TEXT_FORMAT_BODY"
      }
     },
     Subject: {
      Charset: "UTF-8",
      Data: "Test email"
     }
    },
  Source: "xyxy@gmail.com",
  ReplyToAddresses: [
     "xyxy@gmail.com",
  ],
};

const sendPromise = new AWS.SES({apiVersion: "2010-12-01"}).sendEmail(params).promise();

sendPromise.then(function(data) {
  console.log(data.MessageId);
}).catch(
  function(err) {
  console.error(err, err.stack);
});

return Promise.resolve(true);
}
}
```

I am in a sanbox environment and both of those emails are verified. Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you tried using `import {AWS} from 'aws-sdk'` ?

Comment: I have `const AWS = require("aws-sdk");`

Comment: Yes,  but since you are in typescript I am not sure if that work the way it should.

Comment: I tried `import {AWS} from 'aws-sdk'` but that is a syntax error. It doesnt find AWS in aws-sdk but takes `const AWS = require("aws-sdk");`

Answer (score 9):

This works for me

```
import { SES, AWSError } from 'aws-sdk';
import { SendEmailRequest, SendEmailResponse } from 'aws-sdk/clients/ses';

const ses = new SES();

const params: SendEmailRequest = {
    Source: sender,
    Destination: {
        ToAddresses: [
            recipient
        ]
    },
    Message: {
        Subject: {
            Data: subject,
            Charset: charset
        },
        Body: {
            Text: {
                Data: body,
                Charset: charset
            },
            Html: {
                Data: html,
                Charset: charset
            }
        }
    }
}

ses.sendEmail(params, (err: AWSError, data: SendEmailResponse) => {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
    else console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

With AWS SDK v-3:

```
    const sesClient = new SESClient({ region: REGION });
    const paramsForEmail = {
        Destination: {
            ToAddresses: [email],
        },
        Message: {
            Body: {
                Html: {
                    Charset: "UTF-8",
                    Data: `
                    <p>              
                      Hello world!
                    </p>
                    `
                }
            },
            Subject: { Data: "Hello World" },
        },
        Source: EMAIL_FROM,
        ReturnPath: EMAIL_RETURN,
    };
    const resultEmail = await sesClient.send( new SendEmailCommand(paramsForEmail) );
    sesClient.destroy();
```

Answer (score 1):

Using async lambda functions and [AWS-SDK SES with promises](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/ses-examples-sending-email.html):

```
import { Handler } from 'aws-lambda';
import { SES } from 'aws-sdk';

type Event = {
  ...
};

export const handler: Handler<Event> = async (event: Event) => {
  try {
    const params: SendEmailRequest = {
      ...
    }
    var result = await ses.sendEmail(params).promise();
  } catch (exception) { ...
  }
};
```